# Get all string values from a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object, with nested objects. How do I target a specific index of the object and loop through all the nested values of `image`. As you will note the length of the nested objects vary.

Target example: `productArray[0].image` = test1.png, test2.png, test3.png

```
var products =  [
    //item1
    {
        identifier: "item-0",
        image: {
            "img1": "test1.png",
            "img2": "test2.png",
            "img3": "test3.png"
        }
    },
    //item2
    {
        identifier: "item-1", 
        image: {
            "img1": "test1.png",
            "img2": "test2.png"
        }
    },
    //item3
    {
        identifier: "item-2", 
        image: {
            "img1": "test1.png",
            "img2": "test2.png",
            "img3": "test3.png",
            "img4": "test4.png",
            "img5": "test5.png",
            "img6": "test6.png",
            "img7": "test7.png"
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: You should accept an answer that solves your problem to show appreciation to other users who tried to help you. This is how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this. What you need to do is a simple loop through the object at a specific index, or you can target them all. Note that the `image` object is not an array, so it will not have an accurate `length` property.

Target all indexes:

```
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  console.log("Item: " + i);
  var images = products[i].image;
  for(var a in images)
   console.log(images[a]);
}
```

Target specific:

```
for(var i in products[0].image)
    console.log(products[0].image[i]);
```

I used a for loop here, but you can use a while loop if you would like.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/uGNF9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var strs = (function( obj ) {
    var ret = [];
    for( im in obj ) {
         ret.push( obj[im] );
         //You could access each image URL here
         //ad strs in the end will have all of them 
         //comma-separated after this code completes
         // im is the key, obj[ im ] the value
    }
    return ret.join(',');
})( products[0].image );

console.log( strs );
```

[**WORKING JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/3Qv5e/)

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1. You need to iterate over your original array of products. **products**
2. Each element (product) will be in format { identifier: "", image : {"img1" : "img2", ..}} **products[i]**
3. You get the image property of current product - this is an object. **products[i].image**
4. Now you need to iterate over the properties of the image object. **products[i].image[j]**

**Code:**

```
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++)
{
  for(var j in products[i].image)
  {
    // Here you have all the images for the current product.
    // You can print them, group them or whatever you want to do with them
    console.log(products[i].image[j]); 
  }
}
```

Also you can change the code (introduce variables) to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing this, with newer functions in ECMAScript 5

```
var images = Object.keys(products[2].image).map(function(key){
    return products[2].image[key]
})

console.log(images) // Returns: ["test1.png", "test2.png", "test3.png", "test4.png", "test5.png", "test6.png", "test7.png"]
```

#### How It Works:

`Object#keys` returns an array of key names. `Array#map` creates a new array using the keys from `Object#keys`. By looking up the key from the object you get the value, which will be the image name.

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s9ZjB/)**